# What is a valid Unix timestamp. Shows an error on FCC?

Tags: express, microservices

I am trying to solve a FCC microservice project question and am stuck at this point "It should handle a valid unix date, and return the correct unix timestamp". What does this actually mean???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I needed this ---

```
if (/\d{5,}/.test(reqDate)) 
{
    var dateInt = parseInt(reqDate);
    //Date regards numbers as unix timestamps, strings are processed differently
    res.json({ unix: reqDate, utc: new Date(dateInt).toUTCString() });
}
```